# Node.js cassandra connection timeout

Tags: node.js, cassandra

I'm receiving a timeout on connection to cassandra instance using Node js
Cassandra version: 3.9
Node js:  v6.9.1
I'm connecting using this driver: https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver

Here is my code snippet:

```
const express = require('express');
const cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');
const async = require('async');

// Constants
const PORT = 8080;
const CASSANDRA_PORT = process.env['CASSANDRA_PORT'];
const CASSANDRA_PATH = '127.0.0.1';

// App
const app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', './views');

var client = new cassandra.Client({contactPoints: [CASSANDRA_PATH], protocolOptions: {port: CASSANDRA_PORT}});

client.on('log', function(level, className, message, furtherInfo) {
  console.log('log event: %s -- %s', level, message);
});

client.connect(function (e, m) {
  console.log(e);
  console.log(m);
});
```

Error stacktrace:

```
log event: info -- Adding host 127.0.0.1:7000
log event: info -- Getting first connection
log event: info -- Connecting to 127.0.0.1:7000
log event: verbose -- Socket connected to 127.0.0.1:7000
log event: info -- Trying to use protocol version 4
log event: verbose -- Sending stream #0
log event: verbose -- Sent stream #0 to 127.0.0.1:7000
log event: info -- Connection to 127.0.0.1:7000 closed
log event: warning -- There was an error when trying to connect to the host 127.0.0.1
log event: warning -- Connection to 127.0.0.1:7000 could not be created: OperationTimedOutError: The host 127.0.0.1:7000 did not reply before timeout 12000 ms
log event: warning -- Connection pool to host 127.0.0.1:7000 could not be created
{ [Error: All host(s) tried for query failed. First host tried, 127.0.0.1:7000: OperationTimedOutError: The host 127.0.0.1:7000 did not reply before timeout 12000 ms. See innerErrors.]
  innerErrors: 
   { '127.0.0.1:7000': 
      { Error: The host 127.0.0.1:7000 did not reply before timeout 12000 ms
          at OperationTimedOutError.DriverError (
        message: 'The host 127.0.0.1:7000 did not reply before timeout 12000 ms',
        info: 'Represents a client-side error that is raised when the client did not hear back from the server within socketOptions.readTimeout' } },
  info: 'Represents an error when a query cannot be performed because no host is available or could be reached by the driver.',
  message: 'All host(s) tried for query failed. First host tried, 127.0.0.1:7000: OperationTimedOutError: The host 127.0.0.1:7000 did not reply before timeout 12000 ms. See innerErrors.' }
undefined
```

FYI, Keyspace is created in advance.
How can I avoid this timeout exception during server start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are connecting to the wrong port.
The default port for the Apache Cassandra native protocol is 9042 but it looks you are trying to use 7000.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/security/secureFireWall_r.html

Try connecting using cqlsh.
Look at the `native_transport_port` setting in the cassandra.yaml file (9042 by default).

Comment: Thanks, 9042 port establishing helped me with connection!